# Adding a Select Field to PHP form

Tags: php, wordpress

I am following [this tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/build-your-own-wordpress-contact-form-plugin-in-5-minutes/) and it is all going well and works brilliantly. I've been able to change and add the relevant fields I need... All except one. I am trying to add a 'Select' field so visitors can select their inquiry type from the list. I've attempted it a few different ways, however with literally no experience in PHP I'm finding this difficult.

Could anyone give me some guidance towards how to do so?

Thanks very much.

Comment: Can you post your code that shows what you've tried so far which will be helpful.

Comment: Yes, please show us what you have.  People here are willing to help but you need to meet us at least halfway

Comment: @nomistic As my code was almost identical to the tutorial I didn't see the point in posting it as I thought it would bulk up the question more than it needed to be. I will always include it from now on though, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty bad tutorial
Horrific code

Just add the `<select>` inside the form.  Then style with CSS.

```
echo '<form action="' . esc_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) . '" method="post">';
echo '<select><option>Option 1</option><option>Option 2</option><option>Option 3</option></select>';
echo '<p>';
```

This is better code:

```
$uri = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'];
$cf_name = htmlspecialchars( $_POST["cf-name"] ) ;
$cf_email = htmlspecialchars( $_POST["cf-email"] );
$cf_subject = htmlspecialchars( $_POST["cf-subject"]);
$cf_message = htmlspecialchars( $_POST["cf-message"]);

echo <<<EOF
<form action="$uri" method="post">
<select><option>Option 1</option><option>Option 2</option><option>Option 3</option></select>
<p>Your Name (required) <br/>
<input type="text" name="cf-name" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+" value="$cf_name" size="40" /></p>
<p>Your Email (required) <br/><input type="email" name="cf-email" value="$cf_email" size="40" /></p>
<p>Subject (required) <br/><input type="text" name="cf-subject" pattern="[a-zA-Z ]+" value="$cf_subject" size="40" /></p>
<p>Your Message (required) <br/>
<textarea rows="10" cols="35" name="cf-message">$cf_message</textarea></p>
<p><input type="submit" name="cf-submitted" value="Send"></p>
</form>
EOF;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for your help. What makes this code so bad out of interest? Would it disrupt anything on the page if I put it on there?

Comment: It is very typical of programmers that started out with WordPress.  Notice how I wrote the same code.  One echo instruction.  The bad code had one echo instruction for every line, very bad style.  The thing that is indicative of WP is continual switching PHP in and out of PHP and HTML mode with no regard for the significant amount of overhead PHP requires to do the switching.  In general, WordPress is an example of the worst PHP programing in nearly everything way possible.  I read a WP programming book by their top programmer.  He is no programmer, he is faking it.

Comment: After pondering you question, when I see someone's code I can tell they got their programming roots with WP.  It's a handicap.  WP also makes a lot of the worst HTML pages on the Internet. View source, the HTML even looks ugly.  Worse it is technically horrific.  Run W3C HTML and CSS validators on any WP site. Even worse is the `<head>` HTML.  All CSS links (should be 1link max) should be place above all JS links.  Interleaving CSS and JS is very very bad.  The Browser needs all CSS to start rendering.  It parses JS as it is encountered.  It restarts rendering when CSS is found after JS.